# Converting Html file to pdf, or xlsx in r

Tags: r

I created a correlation matrix using the code below. It shows up in r as an html file. Is there a way I can convert and export the html file as an xlsx or even pdf file?

```
library(sjPlot)
data(mtcars)
tab_corr(mtcars, corr.method="spearman", na.deletion="pairwise",  p.numeric =TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: In R? Otherwise you can convert online.

Comment: Thanks for the response. works great for the pdf. For the xlsx, once the code excutes and I click on "Export Table", nothing happens.

Comment: You have to download the js files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **webshot** package to convert the HTML file to a PDF file.

```r
library(sjPlot)
data(mtcars)
tabl <- tab_corr(
  mtcars, corr.method = "spearman", na.deletion = "pairwise",  p.numeric = TRUE
)
# save the HTML table to a file
writeLines(tabl$page.complete, "correlationTable.html")

# convert to PDF file
webshot::webshot(
  url = "correlationTable.html",
  file = "correlationTable.pdf"
)
```

The result is very good.

---

## Edit: convert to xlsx

To convert to xlsx, you can use the JavaScript library [TableExport](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport).

```r
library(sjPlot)
data(mtcars)
tabl <- tab_corr(
  mtcars, corr.method = "spearman", na.deletion = "pairwise",  p.numeric = TRUE
)
# save the HTML table to a file
writeLines(tabl$page.content, "table.html")


library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

js_export <- 
  "
var $table = $('table');
var instance = $table.tableExport({
  formats: ['xlsx'],
  exportButtons: false,
  filename: 'myTable',
  sheetname: 'Sheet1'
});
var exportData0 = instance.getExportData();
var exportData = exportData0[Object.keys(exportData0)[0]]['xlsx'];
instance.export2file(exportData.data, exportData.mimeType, exportData.filename, 
                     exportData.fileExtension, exportData.merges, 
                     exportData.RTL, exportData.sheetname);
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    # put these files in the www subfolder
    tags$script(src = "xlsx.core.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "FileSaver.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "tableexport.min.js")
  ),
  
  includeHTML("table.html"),
  
  actionButton("export", "Export table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$export, {
    runjs(js_export)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:

[image]